# How to equally balance $\|X\|_1$ over the columns of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following optimization

$$\min_X f(X)+\lambda \|X\|_1,$$
in which $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, and $\|X\|_1=\sum_{i,j} |x_{ij}|$, and $f(X)$ is differentiable in $X$.

It is ideal for me to have a small value for $\|X\|_1$ which is equally balanced over the columns of $X$.

For example, I like to have $\|X_{:,i}\|_1 \approx \|X_{:,j}\|_1~\forall i,j$, where $X_{:,i}$ denotes colimn $i$ of $X$.

Specifically, I want to prevent situations in which $X$ has a few columns with large entries and a lot of columns with very small entries, assuming $f(X)$ allows those situations.

Comment: you could have a different $\lambda$ for each column, and keep adjusting $\lambda$ until you are satisfied

Comment: @LinAlg yes, but it would not be easy especially when $k$ is large (e.g 100 or more)

Comment: that the problem is not easy is to be expected, since setting a lower bound on a norm is difficult from an optimization perspective

Comment: If you can assume you know the sign of each element (Either by other constants in the model or force a sign on the elements) you may try do something like total variation on the columns sum.